# Display 2 types of data in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 2 types of user `Athletes` and `Teams`. I created 3 tables `users`,`athletes` & `teams`. I am storing username & password in `users` table and others information in  `athletes` & `teams` table.  I would like to  display `Athletes` and `Teams` information in home page.

My User model is like below

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];

    protected $fillable = ['email','password','remember_token','category_id'];

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Team::class);
    }

    public function athlete()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Athlete::class);
    }
}
```

My Team model is like below

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{    
  public $guarded = [];

  protected $fillable = ['first_name','last_name','user_id','how_did_find','social_media',];

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
}
```

My Athlete model is like below

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Athlete extends Model
{    
  public $guarded = [];

  protected $fillable = ['user_id','social_media','youtube_video','website'];

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
}
```

I am using below code in controller.

```
$staff_picks = User::orderBy('id','desc')->take(10)->with('athlete','team')->get();
```

Comment: Show us your models and what you already tried.

Comment: Your will surely write the code. Won't you?

Comment: @azeós, I edited my question.

Comment: What are `active()` and  `notAdmin()`. They are not defined in the user model

Comment: It seems that you don't have method 'category' in your user model, based on query you are using. try like `$staff_picks = User::notAdmin()->active()->orderBy('id','desc')->take(10)->with('athlete','team')->get();
`

Comment: Yes. As well as there is not `category` too

Comment: @ZainFarooqm sorry, I used previous code.

Comment: @VijaySankhat,  sorry, I used previous code.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: @VijaySankhat, no, actually I would like to display users information which are in those two tables.

Comment: Are your other tables populated as well?

Comment: What are you getting in your query result? show us result of `dd($staff_picks);`

Comment: @VijaySankhat, Here is the dd()  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L3MD.png  . How can I iterate the result ?

Comment: Do like this `foreach($staff_picks as $r){
    $r->teams->social_media; //(Must check for null)
 $r->athletes->social_media; //(Must check for null)
}`

Comment: Please use updated code..

Comment: Hi all, Please up-vote my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is how it should be**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];

    protected $fillable = ['email','password','remember_token','category_id'];

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Team::class);
    }

    public function athlete()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Athlete::class);
    }
}


class Team extends Model
{    
  public $guarded = [];

  protected $fillable = ['first_name','last_name','user_id','how_did_find','social_media',];

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
}

class Athlete extends Model
{    
  public $guarded = [];

  protected $fillable = ['user_id','social_media','youtube_video','website'];

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
}
```

And the query

```
$staff_picks = User::orderBy('id','desc')->take(10)->with('athlete','team')->get();
```

And the iteration

```
foreach($staff_picks as $r){ 
    $r->teams->social_media; //(user can be either teams or athletes so must check for null) 
    $r->athletes->social_media; //(user can be either teams or athletes so must check for null) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In athlete & team model create a column called user_id and in user model create two methods as hasMany relation for athletes and teams models. 
After login get the data as

```
User::where('id', 1)->with('teams', 'athletes')->first();
```

Relations inside User modal can be written as below.

```
teams() {
  return $this->hasMany(Team::class);
}
athletes() {
  return $this->hasMany(Athlete::class);
}
```