# Can I Get Relation Data Without Loop (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, migration

For example, I have some models and related tables, they are :

> 1. Permohonan (table name: peminjam)
>
>    - id
>    - nama_lengkap
> 2. Klasifikasi
>
>    - id
>    - penerima_id
>    - kriteria_id
>    - sub_kriteria_id
> 3. kriteria
>
>    - id
>    - nama_kriteria
> 4. SubKriteria (table name: sub_kriteria)
>
>    - id
>    - nama_sub_kriteria
>    - bobot

they are well connected, but I want create an array that holds relationship data from the klasifikasi table.

this is the content of klasifikasi table :

```
| id | peminjam_id | kriteria_id | sub_kriteria_id |
| 72 | 16          | 1           | 12              |
| 73 | 16          | 2           | 7               |
| 74 | 16          | 3           | 13              |
| 75 | 17          | 1           | 14              |
| 76 | 17          | 2           | 6               |
| 77 | 17          | 3           | 20              |
```

Oke, and this is my php code in Controller :

```
public function index()
    {
        $q = Permohonan::all();
        foreach($q as $peminjam){
            $cls = Permohonan::find($peminjam->id);
            foreach($cls->kriteria as $kriteria){
                $kriteriaID[$peminjam->id][$kriteria->id] = "sub_kriteria_id";
            }
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($kriteriaID);
    }
```

output :

```
Array
(
    [16] => Array
        (
            [1] => sub_kriteria_id
            [2] => sub_kriteria_id
            [3] => sub_kriteria_id
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [1] => sub_kriteria_id
            [2] => sub_kriteria_id
            [3] => sub_kriteria_id
        )
)
```

in the second array, can I put id instead of sub_kriteria table into array value? so the output is as follows like this :

```
Array
    (
        [16] => Array
            (
                [1] => 12
                [2] => 7
                [3] => 13
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [1] => 14
                [2] => 6
                [3] => 20
            )
    )
```

I hope any body can help me to solve this case. Thank you..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177925/display-2-types-of-data-in-laravel/58181577#58181577

Answer (score 0):

Laravel relationship is the best way to achieve your desired result:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships